# How add class to parent in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor, wrapper, parent, addclass

I use simpleuploads plugin.
When images are uploaded i need add to parent of them a class.

This is HTML code wich is pasted after image upload process

```
<div><img src="link/to/image"><img src="link/to/image2"></div>
```

Now i need to add class to the 'div' element but i don't know how.
To remove *height* and *width* attributes of < img > elements i use this code:

```
<script>
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(e) {
    e.editor.on( 'simpleuploads.finishedUpload' , function(ev)
    {
            var element = ev.data.element;
            if (element.getName() == 'img')
            {
                var img = element.$;
                img.removeAttribute('width');
                img.removeAttribute('height');
                ev.stop(); // Stop the event in case the listener is inserted twice
            }
    });
});
</script>
```

so will be great if someone can help me to add class using it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the right code:

```
<script>
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(e) {
e.editor.on( 'simpleuploads.finishedUpload' , function(ev)
{
        var element = ev.data.element;
        if (element.getName() == 'img')
        {
            var img = element.$;
            img.removeAttribute('width');
            img.removeAttribute('height');
            img.parentNode.setAttribute('class','classname');
            ev.stop(); // Stop the event in case the listener is inserted twice
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I think you can accept this yourself as the approved answer